# Where should I put yii framework and protected files?

Tags: yii

I am playing with yii, bud I am not sure where to put the framework files. At my shared hosting I have /home/username folder which of course contains public_html. Yii aplication files are supposed go into public_html, but what about the framework? Should it also be placed within public_html or should I place it in /home/username? Would that even work? What about protected folder? Should I leave it together with all the other application files in public_html or should it be moved somewhere else as well?

What is the common way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cool thing about most webservers is that it's not a problem to have your actual code a level up higher than the public code. What I use is usually like this:

```
   pubic_html/        <- your /home/user/public_html
     mysite.com/
       public/        <- The web site root (for apache config)
       protected/     <- Your actual code
       dependencies/  <- Framework and other libraries you use
       db/            <- All database delta scripts
```

If multiple of your sites use the same libs you can also opt to put them in a common location and add symlinks to it, so you don't use up your server quota with multiple copies. I think you have to ave the FollowSymlinks option enabled for that though if you are using Apache.

IMO limiting what is publicly available to the public/ folder is a good thing. It adds a little bit of extra protection, given that your actual code folder is not accessible from the outside world.

Edit: As I mentioned in my above comment: If your host only allows a single site and it's pre-linked to public_html you could consider an alternative structure where you split everything:

```
   protected_html/
       code/          <- Your actual code
       dependencies/  <- Framework and other libraries you use
       db/            <- All database delta scripts

   pubic_html/        <- your /home/user/public_html and website root.
```

Yii is pretty versatile with allowing configuration for this, the config file is assumed to be  under the protected/config folder and whatever is a level higher is considered the location of the models/controllers and so on. Between Rolands answer to include Yii from the other location and a modified include of your config file you should be fine to go.

Comment: hm, I am not completely sure I follow all the details.. what would then reside in my /home/user/public_html (the second option you mentioned, since that is what I have, hosting for a single site). would it contain only yii's index.php which would link to protected_html (which would have my code inside code/ ?

Comment: Exactly. Your index.php, any javascript and css files you want publicly available and normally your assets folder, so that Yii can publish files needed by widgets etc.

Comment: Blizz, thanks for the post. I have an Yii application where the developer dumped all the folders at the same level. I would _really_ like to put my app files in a /protected folder called /app so that I can grep, synchronize files etc without going through 1000s of superfluous files. But when I do, the app breaks with "unable to resolve the request" errors. Is there another place to configure where the models, views, controllers are located?

Answer (score 1):

I usually place them in /home/username , this ensures that no-one could ever access the framework directly. Then once placed there edit the index.php file in public_html to point to the framework directory

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/yii.php';
```

You can place the framework inside the public_html folder as well and then just add a .htaccess file in the framework folder containing the following `deny from all` assuming override all is enabled in apache, this will also ensure that no-one can access the directory from the browser.

So whereever possible the files and folders that you do not need to be accessed directly from the browser always place them outside the public_html folder for better security assuming that override all in apache is disabled

Comment: does that mean that "protected" should also be moved outside the public_html?

Comment: There might be a little confusion with the public_html that your hosting provider added for you and the actual document root your webserver will use. public_html is usually just a convention where you place all your sites under in a subfolder (www.mysite.com). Then you create a VHost for that site. specifying that folder as web-root. for Yii, the policy is to have another "public" folder in there that will be the actual web-root. If your host only allows you one site, I would definitely only put Yii's public folder contents there and the rest somewhere else.